Consequences of using collect instead of collectAsStateWithLifecycle
In the following code, what are potential consequences of using just collect instead of collectAsStateWithLifecycle :
@Composable
fun HomeRoute(
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel,
    isExpandedScreen: Boolean,
    openDrawer: () -> Unit,
    snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
) {
    // UiState of the HomeScreen
    val uiState by homeViewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    HomeRoute(
        uiState = uiState,
        isExpandedScreen = isExpandedScreen,
        onToggleFavorite = { homeViewModel.toggleFavourite(it) },
        onSelectPost = { homeViewModel.selectArticle(it) },
        onRefreshPosts = { homeViewModel.refreshPosts() },
        onErrorDismiss = { homeViewModel.errorShown(it) },
        onInteractWithFeed = { homeViewModel.interactedWithFeed() },
        onInteractWithArticleDetails = { homeViewModel.interactedWithArticleDetails(it) },
        onSearchInputChanged = { homeViewModel.onSearchInputChanged(it) },
        openDrawer = openDrawer,
        snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState,
    )
}

